# Can't use localhost as src of iframe

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to display in the popup (when a user click extension icon) a page that has an `url` of `localhost`, in this page I will check if a user is logged in my site and depend on status I will display content in the page.
So I tried these:

First:

- create a `popup.html` (that doesn't contain the `iframe`)
- in `popup.js` create an `iframe` and give it an `src`, `width`, `height`. than append it to the body.

Second:

- in the popup.html add the iframe with the src of localhost.
- in popup.js create an iframe and give it an src, width, height. than append it to the body.

Neither the first nor the second works. and I get this:
[image]

But when I use a normal site in `src`, like `http://bing.com` it works and show the page of bing.com

Comment: Do you have a web server on you machine that is able to serve the iframe or are you trying to load it from a file?

Comment: the page that I'm trying to load in `iframe` rendered by the server of localhost.

Comment: For sure the server does not renders but at maximum serves the page (the client renders), and the answer you gave makes me stress this point: are you completely sure you  installed a web-server and configured it to serve a specific web pages, such that when you go to `http://localhost` you see your web page?

Comment: Yes, when I type the url passed in the  `src`  of `iframe` I got the page.

Comment: And which is the content of `src`?

Comment: `src=http://localhost:8888/portal/publications/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174986/discussion-between-matteo-ragni-and-oussama-he).

Answer (score 0):

This is a MVCE example that I developed:

The HTML files are:

`index.html` is the file that is served through the web server

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

`popup.html` is the extension popup content

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <script src="content.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

with the manifest for the extension:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Popup",
  "version": "0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Popup Test",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All you need is a server for the external file to include, I used ruby:

`serve.rb`

```
require 'webrick'
s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8888, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd).start
```

All the magic happens in the content javascript:

`content.js`

```
function addiframe() {
  div = document.getElementById("container");
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');

    frame.setAttribute('width', '500px');
    frame.setAttribute('height', '500px');
    frame.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
    frame.setAttribute('id', 'inject');
  frame.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:8888');

    div.appendChild(frame);
};

addiframe();
```

and this is an image that shows the result:

[image]